# Extract value of a particular column name in pandas as listed in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

The title wasn't too clear but here's an example. Suppose I have:

```
person  apple  orange  type
Alice   11     23      apple
Bob     14     20      orange
```

and I want to get this column

```
person new_col
Alice  11
Bob    20
```

so we get the column 'apple' for row 'Alice' and 'orange' for row 'Bob'.

I'm thinking iterrows, but that would be slow. Are there faster ways to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
df['new_col'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['type'])
print (df)
  person  apple  orange    type  new_col
0  Alice     11      23   apple       11
1    Bob     14      20  orange       20
```

If want only 2 column DataFrame use [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) or `DataFrame` contructor:

```
df1 = df[['person']].assign(new_col=df.lookup(df.index, df['type']))
print (df1)
  person  new_col
0  Alice       11
1    Bob       20
```

---

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'person':df['person'].values,
        'new_col':df.lookup(df.index, df['type'])},
         columns=['person','new_col'])
print (df1)
  person  new_col
0  Alice       11
1    Bob       20
```